# Probability of perfectly assembling a cube

Tags: probability

Suppose that a white cube is painted red on the outside, then separated into $n^3$ identical smaller cubes, then randomly assembled. What is the probability that the reassembled cube is all red on the outside?

Comment: OK, what have you tried?

Comment: What is the probability the top left front corner looks correct (if $n>2$). What about other cubes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $(n^3)!\cdot24^{n^3}$ ways of reassembling the cube if we give every cubie an orientation. The number of ways to reassemble that preserve the red outside is the product of

- $8!\cdot3^8$ ways to place/orient the corner cubies
- $(12(n-2))!\cdot2^{12(n-2)}$ ways to place/orient the edge cubies
- $(6(n-2)^2)!\cdot4^{6(n-2)^2}$ ways to place/orient the central face cubies
- $((n-2)^3)!\cdot24^{(n-2)^3}$ ways to place/orient the interior cubies.

So the final probability is
$$\frac{8!\cdot3^8\cdot(12(n-2))!\cdot2^{12(n-2)}\cdot(6(n-2)^2)!\cdot4^{6(n-2)^2}\cdot((n-2)^3)!\cdot24^{(n-2)^3}}{(n^3)!\cdot24^{n^3}}$$